# easy way to parse HTML into jQuery usable object

Tags: jquery, html

Say i want to insert a large block of HTML directly into another element, example:

```
<div class ="test">
<p class ="ptest"> Mauris blandit <span class ="span1">aliquet elit,</span>
eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. </p> </div>
```

its really easy to do this with:

```
jquery.append("")
```

however this means i will have to format all the HTML first (removing line breaks, replacing " with ' etc).

Is there a method to do this automatically within jQuery or is this something i just need to do manually?

Comment: you can put your html in single quotes (like you would do when echoing out html in php)

Comment: I think you have to do it manually. Or you can create a macro in your text editor to do it for you if you need it very often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive run into the same problem a couple of times en this helped me a lot. Maybe that it can help you to.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/

```
<div id="log">
  <h3>Content:</h3>
</div>

<script>
var $log = $( "#log" ),
  str = "hello, <b>my name is</b> jQuery.",
  html = $.parseHTML( str ),
  nodeNames = [];

// Append the parsed HTML
$log.append( html );

// Gather the parsed HTML's node names
$.each( html, function( i, el ) {
  nodeNames[ i ] = "<li>" + el.nodeName + "</li>";
});

// Insert the node names
$log.append( "<h3>Node Names:</h3>" );
$( "<ol></ol>" )
  .append( nodeNames.join( "" ) )
  .appendTo( $log );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

very simple:

```
var html = $('.ptest').clone();
 $('.test').append(html);
```

Comment: this wouldnt work as the HTML block i would want to append would not already exist on the page. I mean if say i hand write some HTML in notepad or something and want to append that to an existing element without the hassle of manually altering it all beforehand